# Call sourceGenerators manually in sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I am using `sourceGenerators in Compile` to generate some Scala source files to target\scala-2.10\src_managed. When I run `sbt compile`the sources are generated and compiled along with the regular code under src\main\scala.

But what if I want to generate the sources separately without compiling? What I am looking for is this flow:

1. call a task to generate source code
2. use the generated sources for IDE assistance in my regular sources
3. compile everything

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Have you read these posts: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11652418/3248346, http://stackoverflow.com/a/11640883/3248346?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *make use of*? Is this a question about IDE setup? Because you can of course cross reference from generated to unmanaged sources and the other way around...

Comment: @I.K: yes I have read the posts but if you use sourceGenerators, I don't see how you can generate code without running `sbt compile`. I have now added a Generators.scala file in the project folder in my application. Then I have added a new task (makeGamedata) in my build.sbt which uses the Generators class to generate source code. So my development cycle is now: `sbt makeGamedata` > wrote code on `src/main/scala` that is using the generated source > `sbt compile` to compile everything. This works good. Now I need to figure out how to unit test code in the project folder ..

Comment: @Martin Ring: Martin, yes that works fine but they are always generated and compiled together. I would like to do the generation as an extra task, i.e. `sbt generate` to generate source code in `src_managed` > develop code that uses these source in `src/main/scala` > compile everything.

Comment: @reikje: I still don't understand what you mean by code that *uses* these sources?

Comment: @MartinRing simple example: you generate Class A then you manually write a Class B which creates an instance of Class A

Comment: @reikje: Why wouldn't that be possible with your existing configuration? It doesn't matter if the Class A is generated before or after you write class B - as long as they are compiled together. I ask once again: Is this a question about IDE setup?

Comment: @MartinRing: no it's not about IDE setup. First of all, how can you write Class B before A exists? You can't, you need two `sbt compile` runs. First run: generates Class A in src_managed. Then you write a Class B in src which uses Class A. Then seconds `sbt compile` run to compile both. Now the problem is, what happens if the generator makes an incompatible change to Class A. Then you would get a compile error.

Comment: Why is it necessary for class A to exist when *writing* class B? It only has to exist when compiling...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

If I got you correct now, you want to be able to call the source generators seperately. For that you can simply define a custom task like this somewhere in your `/build.sbt` or `/project/Project.scala` file:

```
val generateSources = taskKey[List[File]]("generate sources")

generateSources <<= 
  (sourceGenerators in Compile) { _.join.map(_.flatten.toList) }
```

you can then call the generator manually from the sbt console like this:

```
> generateSources
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed 07.04.2014 13:42:41
```

*Side Note:*
I would however reccomend to setup your IDE to generate the sources if the only thing you need them for is to get IDE support.

---

**Old answer for future reference**

You don't need to do anything special to use a generated class or object from a non-generated class or object.

In your `/build.sbt` or `/project/Project.scala` file you define the source generator:

```
sourceGenerators in Compile <+= sourceManaged in Compile map { dir =>
  val file = dir / "A.scala"
  IO.write(file, "class A(val name: String)")
  Seq(file)
}
```

Then you write some code which creates an instance of class A in`/src/main/scala/B.scala`:

```
object B extends App {
  val a = new A("It works")
  println(a.name)
}
```

If you compile this code from sbt, it will consider both generated and non-generated code at compilation:

```
> run
[info] Compiling 2 scala sources to <...>
[info] Running B
It works
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed 07.04.2014 13:15:47
```

Comment: Yes but in your example you write object B before A.scala exists, which will be hard without proper IDE support and with complex classes. Also let's say the code generation depends on some XML files that may change and suddenly A doesn't have a name property anymore. Then your compilation will fail.

Comment: Ok. Now I finally understood, what your question is. See my update.