# SBT: input task to generate a test source by name

Tags: scala, sbt

I want to create an sbt task to generate a test source e.g. `sbt genSpec Foo` should generate `FooSpec.scala` in src_managed/test

I tried this:

```
val genSpec = inputKey[File]("Generate spec file")

genSpec := {
  import sbt.complete.DefaultParsers._
  val log = streams.value.log
  val arg: String = spaceDelimited("<arg>").parsed.head //TODO: Single string parser!
  val fileName = s"${arg}Spec"
  log.info(s"Generating $fileName")
  val file = (sourceManaged in Test).value / s"$fileName.scala"
  IO.write(file, s"""class $fileName extends AbstractSpec""")
  //sourceGenerators in Test += file
  file
}
```

But, even though it is created in the sourceManaged directory, sbt test does not pick it up.

But, this works:

```
sourceGenerators in Test += Def.task {
  val file = (sourceManaged in Test).value / "FooSpec.scala"
  IO.write(file, s"""class FooSpec extends AbstractSpec""")
  Seq(file)
}.taskValue
```

But, the above is not exactly what I want - I want to specify Foo as an argument.

So, is there any way to pass arguments to a sourceGenerator task? Or create a task that add something to managed sources such that it is picked up by sbt test?

Also, what is a way to iterate over all compiled sources's filenames? If I can do that, I will simply generate all the Spec.scala from the source filenames itself...

As suggested by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22859879/call-sourcegenerators-manually-in-sbt), I tried this:

```
val genSpec = taskKey[Seq[File]]("Generate spec file")

genSpec := {
  import sbt.complete.DefaultParsers._
  val log = streams.value.log
  val args = spaceDelimited("<arg>").parsed
  args map {arg =>
    val fileName = s"${arg}Suite"
    log.info(s"Generating $fileName")
    val file = (sourceManaged in Test).value / s"$fileName.scala"
    IO.write(file, s"""class $fileName extends AbstractSuite""")
    file
  }
}


genSpec <<= (sourceGenerators in Test) { _.join.map(_.flatten.toList) }
```

But, I got this error:

```
 error: `parsed` can only be used within an input task macro, such as := or Def.inputTask.
  val args = spaceDelimited("<arg>").parsed
                                     ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
val genSpec = inputKey[File]("Generate spec file")

genSpec := {
  import sbt.complete.DefaultParsers._
  val log = streams.value.log
  val arg: String = spaceDelimited("<arg>").parsed.head //TODO: Single string parser!
  val className = s"${arg}Spec"
  val file = (sourceManaged in Test).value / s"$className.scala"
  log info s"Generating $file"
  IO.write(file, s"""class $className extends AbstractSpec""")
  file
}

managedSources in Test ++= ((sourceManaged in Test).value ** "*Spec.scala").get
```