# SBT src_managed not availabe for compilation

Tags: scala, sbt

In my project I have a special SBT plugin to generate some configuration specific settings (like sbt-buildinfo). A special task generates a Scala class and stores it in 'src_managed' folder.

The problem is, that after this file is successfully generated, the following 'compile' can't find this class and I get compilation error.

I have several configurations defined with:

```
compile in conf <<= (compile in conf).dependsOn(mytask)
```

I call this plugin like so:

```
;clean;proj/myconf:compile
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should setup special setting for code generator:

`sourceGenerators in Compile <+= (myCodeGeneratorTask in Compile)`

[SBT generate code using project defined generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11509843/sbt-generate-code-using-project-defined-generator)

Comment: It works, thanks. Do you know how can I trigger a specific generator only? In my project there are several generators (one per configuration). If I follow your approach, all these generators are called.